# How to display Progress Bar in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to display a progress bar or progress dialog while downloading something from server it may be image or anything else. How can I do this in BlackBerry?

Comment: The [GaugeField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/GaugeField.html) should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blackberry kb article might help you: [Sample "Please Wait" screen](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-screen-part-1/ta-p/493808)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @NullUserException yeah i agree. The provided link is actually a blackberry KB article which consist of detail info related to this question, so i thought this will be more helpful. Anyways thanks for your info, i will add some context before providing any link from next time.

Comment: Can you add it this time, too, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are several discussions in the [Blackberry forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?q=progress) that show how to display progress bars during operations.  Showing the progress of a remote download is a common example.