# How i can display progress/indicator dialog in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

i am developing app in 5.0 version.
in my app there is database so when data is coming from db it is taking time so i have to put progress dialog in between. i want to open dialog when data is coming when it fill in all fields then it would be dismiss. does any body have idea for this please send me.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5003386/396949

Answer (score 1):

Check this article http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-quot-Please-Wait-quot-screen-part-1/ta-p/493808

This article is intended provide a fully functioning "Please Wait" sample Popup Screen. It consist of 3 Parts, each part with its own sample code. The most relevant sample to you is **[PleaseWait3.zip](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/java_dev@tkb/426/4/PleaseWait3.zip)** which is located in the part 3 (last parT) since it contains progress bar sample code.

When running it, make sure you change the address of the file to be downloaded in the **"Test that gives percentage updates**" to a valid one since the existing one is invalid (you can use this one for example `http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18095/BlackBerry_Java_SDK-Development_Guide--1239696-0730090812-001-6.0-US.pdf`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a GaugeField as described here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Gauge_field_1303006_11.jsp