# Display the web page in BrowserField after loading the whole page in BlackBerry Java

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am working on an project on which I added a `BrowserField` in my screen.  When  I call this it shows a blank page until the page is loaded.

I want when my complete page is loaded, then I will show it; before that, I show a progress indicator.

Please give your valuable suggestions how I can achieve this task as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For OS 6.0 or higher, you could use [an activity indicator like this](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Activity_indicator_1214556_11.jsp).
- Another option is to [use a GaugeField or an animated GIF image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9374438/119114), as in this answer, based on a sample supplied by Peter Strange (follow the link to blackberry.com for sample code).
- And here's yet another example [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819660/119114), by Max Gontar.

It really depends on how you want it to look and function (and which OS versions you need to support).

If you're using `BrowserField`, and not managing the HTTP connection manually, you can detect the page load finishing with [BrowserFieldListener#documentLoaded()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserFieldListener.html#documentLoaded(net.rim.device.api.browser.field2.BrowserField,%20org.w3c.dom.Document)).