# Loading screen blackberry

Tags: blackberry

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How i can display progress/indicator dialog in Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373778/how-i-can-display-progress-indicator-dialog-in-blackberry)
>   [How to display Progress Bar in BlackBerry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003386/how-to-display-progress-bar-in-blackberry)

I want to show one loading screen just like progress bar in the screen, I don't want that waiting screen but loading just like progress bar. Please help

Answer (score 4):

You may use a GaugeField non blocking component:

> net.rim.device.api.ui.component.GaugeField

following the example at: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Gauge_field_1303006_11.jsp

Comment: Hi, that i know but i want to manage it in version 4.5 and 5.0 also but gauge field is the feature of 6.0 and it will not support in the lower versions.

Comment: And i managed to do that by using .gif image and now it works nice thanks a lot

Comment: In any case: Supported since  BlackBerry® Java® SDK 4.2